# Exclude a sub directory in a protected directory

Tags: htaccess

I need to exclude protection on one of the folder inside a protected directory with .htaccess

I put .htaccess in here:

```
/home/mysite/public_html/new/administrator/.htaccess
```

The directory need to be exclude from protection:

```
/home/mysite/public_html/new/administrator/components/com_phocagallery/
```

My .htaccess file :

```
AuthUserFile "/home/mysite/.htpasswds/public_html/new/administrator/passwd"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "admin"
require valid-user
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/components/com_phocagallery/)$" allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

I tried but not working on my purpose. I suspect my path to the excluded directory may have some mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but I see an error in the following line:

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/components/com_phocagallery/)$" allow`

The leading slash should not be there:

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "(components/com_phocagallery/)$" allow`

The way you have it is relative to the root of the OS instead of relative to the directory the .htaccess file is in.

Comment: are the parenthesis `()` necessary?  I think it is only if you wanted to use `|` to add multiple paths.  I used your leading slash removal advice to allow a php file through and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible using plain old .htaccess directory protection. Maybe you can set up a web based authentication and check for each users rights before accessing directories.

The Apache HTTP server also has a lot of `mod_auth*`-modules, which may help you. See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting environment variables, perhaps you should consider creating a separate set of directives specific to the subdirectory - for example:

`.htaccess` file:

```
AuthUserFile "/home/mysite/.htpasswds/public_html/new/administrator/passwd"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "admin"
require valid-user
Satisfy all
```

`public_subdirectory/.htaccess` file:

```
# All access controls and authentication are disabled
# in this directory
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
```

Directives based upon Apache directives described in [How to accomplish “AuthType None” in Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641646/how-to-accomplish-authtype-none-in-apache-2-2) at StackOverflow.

Comment: Some versions of Apache 2.4.x no longer recognize the `Allow` directive, so in this example, `public_subdirectory/.htaccess` should just contain the line `Require all granted`. (This worked on a NearlyFreeSpeech server for me.)

Comment: This worked for me when I needed public access to .well-known to generate Letsencrypt cert on a password protected wordpress site!  (I needed to create .well-known and put the new htaccess file in that)